# How can I get the parents and childs from the hierarchy in the same order it is in the hierarchy the structure of the hierarchy?

Tags: unity, c#

The line:

```
var gameObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
```

Is getting all the parents and children but not in the order it is in the hierarchy. I tried to use the gos List and to add first the childs then the parents to create a List with all parents and it's childs but it's getting messed. I want to get the structure of the Hierarchy.

```
        var gos = new List<GameObject>();

        var gameObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (gameObjects[i].transform.childCount > 0)
            {

                //get children
                GameObject[] children = new GameObject[gameObjects[i].transform.childCount];
                for (int z = 0; z < children.Length; ++z)
                {
                    children[z] = gameObjects[i].transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
                    gos.Add(children[z].gameObject);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gos.Add(gameObjects[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `else` statement there doesn't need to be there. You have to add the GO whether it has children or not.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? That will help in answering.